# Как добавить элементу Toolbar-а отсуп в Android

Tags: java, android

Решил попробовать использовать Toolbar в приложении,
вот такого вида он у меня сейчас[image: вид]

Не получается добавить отступ между иконками и текстом. Подскажите как мне его добавить? Свойства margin и padding не работают.
Вот мой код:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/action_bar_height"
    android:background="@color/action_bar_background"
    app:contentInsetStart="@dimen/content_insert"
    app:contentInsetEnd="@dimen/content_insert">

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button_previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_previous_activity"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_previous"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_previous_activity"
        android:textSize="@dimen/action_bar_text_size"
        android:textColor="@color/action_bar_text"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/image_button_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_right"
        android:contentDescription="@string/action_next_activity"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_previous_next"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/action_next_activity"
        android:textSize="@dimen/action_bar_text_size"
        android:textColor="@color/action_bar_text"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:onClick="onClick"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: Нарисовать картинку с отступом?

Comment: вариант, но хотелось бы по правильному)

Comment: Оберни все в контейнер, например, `LinearLayout`. Там можешь задать отступы и все, что надо.  Этот контейнер помести в `Toolbar`.

Comment: пробовал, также отступы не работают

Comment: А использовать android:drawableLeft и android:drawableRight для TextView не пробовал? Им можно задать drawablePadding

Comment: У меня проблема не воспроизводится. Задаю для левого `TextView` - `android:paddingLeft="16dp"` и все сдвигается. Аналогично для правого   - `android:paddingRight="16dp"` . Если у вас проблема присутствует, она не в представленной вами разметке, либо вы указываете свойства `padding` неправильно\не тем элементам. Из вашей разметки не видно, где и как вы пытаетесь установить отступы.

Comment: Действительно работает. Спасибо! Из-за layout_gravity = end, не зависимо от разметки image_button_next находится правее текста, должен по идее слева, вот я выходит и напутал, делал отступы этим двум элементам смотря на последовательность в разметке.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос решен, неправильно указал в разметке отступы.

Answer (score 2):

Вариант ужасный, но рабочий.

```
View v = findViewById(android.R.id.home);
if (null != v) {
    ((View) v.getParent().getParent()).setPadding(32, 0, 0, 0);
}
```